# How do I add opencv_contrib to a CMake project?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cmake

I installed OpenCV 3.4 (C++) from source, using CMake.  I reinstalled it using `-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path>`.  I believe this reinstall properly installed opencv_contrib, though I am not positive.  Assume it did install properly.  I have a project that utilizes OpenCV, and I properly include the default OpenCV include directories (I do `include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})`, after `find_package(OpenCV)`). If my C++ project properly finds a non-contrib opencv include file, is there anything more I have to do to get it to recognize an opencv contrib include file?  It's not finding it, but googling showed only an extra lib included in "target_link_libraries", but not an extra directory included for "include_directories".

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so as it turns out, the reinstall with `-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path>` had failed.  So this is kind of a stupid question in the first place.  (Should I delete this question, for the sake of decluttering StackOverflow, or should I leave it up in case someone else likewise makes this stupid mistake?)

Comment: Would have been better if you explained what was wrong... lol